# Php mailer dice que envía correo pero este no llega a gmail

Tags: php, phpmailer

Sucede que cuando envío un mensaje desde el formulario de una página web. Me está diciendo en php que el mensaje ha sido enviado pero este no llega a mi correo. Estoypobando en heroku y cuando reviso la consola de google sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mira que según esto se envía el correo bien lo cual indica que está entrando el en try de mi código:

```js
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/Exception.php'; 
$address=$_POST['address'];
$bedrooms=$_POST['bedrooms'];
$bathrooms=$_POST['bathrooms'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$code=$_POST['code'];
$comments=$_POST['comments'];
$details=$_POST['details'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$extras=$_POST['extras'];
$hours=$_POST['hours'];
$lastName=$_POST['lastName'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$often=$_POST['often'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$preferedDay=$_POST['preferedDay'];
$preferedTime=$_POST['preferedTime'];
$street=$_POST['street'];
$typeClean=$_POST['typeClean'];


$mail = new PHPMailer();

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->isSMTP();                                                 
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';          
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;              
    $mail->Username   = 'mi correo'; //Esto lo edite para el post
    $mail->Password   = 'mipassword';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';         
    $mail->Port       = 587;   
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress('micorreo', 'Jesús');    
    $mail->isHTML(true); 
    $mail->Subject = 'Cleaning requered from ';
    $mail->Body    = "Name: $name  $lastName <br/><br/>".
                     "Email: $email <br/><br/>".
                     "Phone: $phone <br/><br/>".
                     "Street: $street <br/><br/>".
                     "Address: $address <br/><br/>".
                     "Postal Code: $code <br/><br/>".
                     "Type Clean: $typeClean <br/><br/>".
                     "Hours por Clean: $hours <br/><br/>".
                     "How Often?: $often <br/><br/>".
                     "Bedrooms: $bedrooms <br/><br/>".
                     "Extras: $extras <br/><br/>".
                     "Prefered Day: $preferedDay <br/><br/>".
                     "Prefered Time: $preferedTime <br/><br/>".
                     "Comments: $comments <br/><br/>".
                     "Details to the areas: $details \n\n";
                     
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}


?>
```

Según chrome está entando en try del codigo y debería enviar el correo pero no lo hace. Alguna sugerencia ?

Comment: ¿Revisaste en la carpeta `Spam` de Gmail?

Comment: Si, no hay nada

Comment: Prueba con algo así: `if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message enviado con éxito.';
}`

Comment: Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Comment: El mensaje de error te lo dice todo. No se está autenticando en Gmail y por tanto el mensaje no está siendo enviado. Me parece que es un problema conocido y que ha sido tratado antes aquí, revisa las preguntas anteriores. Hay otro problema en la coherencia del código: no está capturando el error en el `catch`, creo que para que capture los errores: tienes que establecer otro modo de debug (actualmente lo tienes establecido a `0`). Pero puedes prescindir del `try catch` si lo deseas, haciendo una verificación de `$mail` y usando `ErrorInfo` o no, pues nunca conviene mostrar mensajes internos